# Mongo query with date condition and join of second collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have my "user" and "userprofile: collection and I need to find a way to get all users which do satisfy my criteria.

First condition is:

> db.userprofile.find(  {       "country":{$ne:""},         "state":{$ne:""}    }
>   ).count()

From my user condition I however need to get all users with certain registration date like this:

> db.user.find(     {created_at: {         $gte:
>   ISODate("2016-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"),         $lt:
>   ISODate("2016-10-27T00:00:00.000Z")     },     }      ).count()

userprofile collection contains field "user_id" which is basically the same value like "id" auto generated field from user collection.

SO question is how can I join all users who match date criteria with all users who match userprofile criteria ?

I tried with sample similar to this one but without success:

> db.user.aggregate([    {
>         $lookup:
>            {
>               from: "userprofile",
>               localField: "_id",
>               foreignField: "userid",
>               as: "user_profile"
>           }    },    {
>           $unwind:"$user_profile"    },    {
>         $match: { "user_profile": 
>             {
>                 "country":{$ne:""}, 
>                 "state":{$ne:""}            }       }    } ]).count()

Update:

db.user.findOne()

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561fac55c9368676ac000001"),
    "username" : "somexxx3",
    "firstname" : "Some",
    "lastname" : "User",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-10-15T13:38:29.954Z"),
    "enabled" : false
}
```

db.userprofile.findOne()

```
db.userprofiles.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ec222017be1b7c763898a4"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("56a77f6c17be1b0a4393d8ea"),
    "email" : "someuser@gmail.com",
    "country" : "United Sates",
    "state" : "New York"
}
```

If someone can help me with this, I would really appreciate it. Any hints are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any errors while doing the above aggregation ?

Comment: @Veeram yeap like $lookup is not recognized, or something similar

Comment: @Splendid which mongodb version are you using?

Comment: @felix -  version()
3.0.10

Comment: @Veeram I updated mongo to 3.2.10 - and now I am not getting errors but I'm not getting any results neithter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query should work :

```
db.user.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:{
         from:"userprofiles",
         localField:"_id",
         foreignField:"user_id",
         as:"user_profile"
      }
   },
   {
      $unwind:"$user_profile"
   },
   {
      $match:{
         "user_profile.country":{
            $ne:""
         },
         "user_profile.state":{
            $ne:""
         },
         created_at:{
            $gte: ISODate("2016-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("2016-10-27T00:00:00.000Z")
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:null,
         count:{
            $sum:1
         }
      }
   }
])
```

the "$group" stage is for counting results (you can't use db.col.aggregate().count()).

The output should look like

```
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 1 }
```

where "count" is the number of matching results

Comment: Tnaks for the answer @felix but I get nothing as output when running this query.

Comment: @Splendid maybe a field mismatch, could you please post the output of db.user.findOne() and db.userprofile.findOne() ?

Comment: I updated a original question, if In match I am using, only match per country/state it works or if I am using only created_at... If it's combined no results.

Comment: @Splendid looks like there is a "s" missing in userprofiles collection name. Try the updated query

Comment: I did... result same thing :(

Comment: @Splendid well it works fine on my machine, the only explanation I can see is that there is no user matching both 'state/country' and 'created_at' condition in your database